# Highcharts - multi line chart - line above line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with two lines that have the same values in some of the points. Which causes one line to be on top of the other while the other line "disappears"
Suggestions on how I can avoid that?
http://jsfiddle.net/t2jyfLds/1/

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 7]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 10]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: How it should look like? Because from mathematical point, when values are the same then are printed in the same position, overlapping.

Comment: what would be the point of avoiding it? If data points are at the same point, they're at the same point.  If you truly need to make sure they don't overlap, you need multiple charts. Any other solution will misrepresent the data.

Comment: If the lines would be stuck one above the other it would be easy to understand  [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/ducL6aw0/)

Comment: But then it is not correct with scale on the yAxis. In example when you have wider lines and then apply small scale in yAxis (tickInterval) then chart will be incorrect, because y values are too high. Mathematically it not makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments in your question have noted, this is the expected behavior when lines sharing the same chart have the same points.

You could give a specific line a z-index value to show it on top of other line(s) in your chart (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.zIndex), but this wouldn't solve the issue of the other line(s) being obscured.

My preferred way to approach this is to use a shared tooltip. That way, when a user hovers over the markers of any of the lines, you'll see the data points of all of them.

See the example screenshot below:

[image]

All you need to do is add `shared: true` to your `tooltip` attribute (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared). You can also use the `formatter` function to give the tooltip more polish with font types, font sizes, etc.

I hope this is helpful for you.